# php header command isn't working

Tags: php, header

I'm having a problem getting this code to work on the website that I'd like to launch soon. In particular when I sign in the header won't redirect after a successful login. I have used this code before many times and I've never had a problem with it. The only difference now is that I'm using a different server and a different database. Here's the code that is giving me trouble:

```
<?php
/*set all the variables*/
$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = sha1($_POST['password']);   /* hash the password*/

$conn = mysqli_connect ('servername', 'username', 'password', 'databasename') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');
/*select the id from the users table that match the conditions*/
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
echo 'Logged in Successfully.';

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];

/*If true head over to the users table*/
header('location: users_table.php');


}
/*If invalid prompt them to adjust the previous entry*/
else {
echo '<h2>Invalid Login</h2><br />';
echo '<h2>Click <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">HERE</a> to go back and adjust your entry.</h2>';
                    }


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

It's not a matter of it connecting properly because I get the message 'successful Login' but it won't redirect at all.

---

Thanks for all the answers, I tried removing the echo but all I get now is a blank page, I thought maybe it was the browser I was using so I switched to another and I still just get a blank page, any other suggestions?

Comment: Try adding an `exit` after your redirect.

Comment: Just `sha1()`ing the password isn't very effective. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNdW5HWBhG0&feature=plcp

Answer (score 5):

You cannot echo anything before your `header` statement.

```
echo 'Logged in Successfully.';
```

This is causing the `header` call to not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($count == 1) {
echo 'Logged in Successfully.';
//this statement is creating problem
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];

/*If true head over to the users table*/
header('location: users_table.php');


}
```

This is because you are echoing something berfore header
You should use `ob_start()` at start and `ob_end_flush()` at the end of the document..

or do not echo before `header()`.As we found you haven't turned on the error.So turn it ON.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be posting the `header` after the `echo`... if this actually worked you'd never see the text (it would simply redirect).  (To fix remove/comment out the `echo` line)

Also the [location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header requires an absolute/full URL (although many browsers seem to cope with relative URLs).

If you want to do it this way (show some sort of status before hand), use an HTML or Javascript redirect that triggers after a couple of seconds.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Logged in Successfully.</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" 
  content="5;url=http://www.example.com/users_table.php"></HEAD>
<BODY>
Logged in Successfully.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Logged in Successfully.</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="setTimeout(function() {
  window.location='http://www.example.com/users_table.php'},5000)">
Logged in Successfully.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Better yet, allow the `users_table.php` page to display a successful login message and use the header-location redirect.