# My PHP header() call isn't working

Tags: php, nginx, raspberry-pi

I set up a little nginx server on my Raspberry Pi for learning web development and maybe sysadmin, except the one thing holding me back from advancing is a `header()` call that isn't working as expected. I couldn't find any incorrect syntax or anything that was answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861288/php-header-command-isnt-working)
 question thread.

```
<?php

if($_POST['username'] == 'admin' && $_POST['password'] == 'not_real_password'){
  header('Location: http://999.999.9.999/loggedIn.html/'); //I have tried both ' and "
} else {
  echo 'Incorrect username or password. <a href="http://999.999.9.999/index.html">Home</a>';
}

?>
```

As a side note, yes, I do know that `999.999.9.999` isn't a real IP address. I was using that to hide my RPi's actual one.

What's supposed to happen is that the browser is supposed to be sent a `loggedIn.html` file but it just goes back to `index.html` which is the page the `$_POST` data was sent through a form. If you don't unerstand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVi4H.png

Comment: Define "isn't working". What is happening? What do you expect to be happening?

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: Are you echo-ing anything before you send the `header()`?

Comment: Might be your seperator. Try `&&` instead of `and`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php

if($_POST['username'] == 'admin' && $_POST['password']){
header('Location: http://999.999.9.999'); //I have tried both ' and "
 } else {
echo 'Incorrect username or password. <a href="http://999.999.9.999/index.html">Home</a>'
}

?>
```

Replace "and" with "&&".

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax failed. You missed off an `;` and the end of this line:

```
echo 'Incorrect username or password. <a href="http://999.999.9.999/index.html">Home</a>'
```

Comment: The last echo doesn't need a closing semi-colon, only for special cases where a class is used. Since the PHP tag is closed, then semi-colon is not required.

Comment: That was just a copying mess-up, I'm SSH-ing into my RPi so I can't really just copy-paste

Comment: In the image you posted, you are being sent to loggedIn.html

Comment: You have a trailing forward slash after loggedIn.html, so that may be causing your issues?